# String searching (containing special character) with %in% does not work while str_detect works

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm doing sentiment analysis and would like to get all bigrams starting with a negation word like "didn't". Using `%in%` works fine with simple string but for those containing a special character like apostrophe, it doesn't work for my text.

Bigrams from the text:

```
> head(sup4_bigrams_count,3)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  word1      word2      n
  <chr>      <chr>  <int>
1 parent’s   day        8
2 mother’s   day        7
3 bachelor’s degree     6

> sup4_bigrams_count$word1 %>% unique  
 ......
 [61] "daily"          "day"            "de"             "define"        
 [65] "depth"          "developed"      "didn’t"         "differentiated"
 [69] "difunctioning"  "diploma"        "doesn’t"        "don’t"
```

I am interest in getting bigrams starting with "didn't", "doesn't" and "don't". But notice in these words it is `’` instead of `'`, so I copied these words straight from the text. Similarly for "doesn't" and "don't". This works but map one word at a time.

```
> sup4_bigrams_count %>% filter(str_detect(word1,"didn’t"))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  word1  word2     n
  <chr>  <chr> <int>
1 didn’t argue     1
2 didn’t miss      1
3 didn’t shame     1
```

But using %in% it doesn't work at all.

```
negate_words <- c("didn’t","doesn’t","don’t")

> sup4_bigrams_count %>% filter(word1 %in% negate_words)
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: word1 <chr>, word2 <chr>, n <int>
```

But if I use these words to create another data frame, %in% works fine.

```
a <- data_frame(word=c("didn’t","doesn’t","don’t"),ind=1:3)
n <- c("didn’t","doesn’t")

> a %>% filter(word %in% n)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  word      ind
  <chr>   <int>
1 didn’t      1
2 doesn’t     2
```

What I can only do is to filter by `str_detect` three times and `rbind` them together, but it is a lot more troublesome and won't be easy if I have a long list of negation words. Hope someone could help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a "OR" regex to search all negative words at once.

```
library(stringr)

negate_words <- c("didn’t","doesn’t","don’t")

strings <-  c("daily",  "day", "de", "define",
              "depth", "developed", "didn’t", "differentiated",
              "difunctioning", "diploma", "doesn’t", "don’t")

str_detect(strings, "didn’t")
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

pattern <- paste0("(", paste(negate_words, collapse="|"), ")")
pattern
# "(didn’t|doesn’t|don’t)"

str_detect(strings, pattern)
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```